# window.location.hash is undefined for ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading content with ajax on a wordpress single page website. I'm trying to have the url changed each time an ajax post is loaded.

Here is the code I use to modify the hash when an item is clicked. The load function is working so I don't add it to the code below for clarity reason (it simply takes the href of the clicked li and load the content in a div).

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

        $('#portfolio-list li:not(#DrawerContainer)').click(function() {

           window.location.hash = "#!" + this.pathname;
           alert(window.location.hash);

        //And here comes the loading part

        return false;
        });

    return false;       
    });
```

Unfortunately the only thing added to my url is `#!undefined`. And alerting `window.location.hash` or `this.pathname` give me the same result.

What do I need to get the pathname returned as a hash in the address bar?

Comment: You're clicking on list items which do not have a `pathname` property. How are you storing the paths in those list items?

Comment: Oh it would have been too easy... Thanks, I didn't know that. 
Do you think turning those LIs into divs might solve the problem? I'll try.

Comment: Not exactly. I mean `this.pathname` does not exist in the `li` context. Do your HTML has something like `<li pathname="...">` or how does it look like?

Comment: Well those LIs are only containers for Divs. The hrefs are in the Divs. like `<li><div class="blabla"><a href="linktothearticle"></a></div></li>`

Comment: this should be closer to what you want http://jsfiddle.net/e7E73/

Comment: Great thanks Fabrício, it's very close but I see it adds the whole href where I only need the end of it (i.e. only the title of the post). Let's say I have this `#!http://localhost/myblog/test-5/` and I only need `#!test-5` to show up. Is this far from what you wrote in the fiddle? Now I'm not sure pathname was the right way to get it... :)

Comment: It's working perfectly thanks a lot ! Can you make an answer so I can accept it? By the way, I thought the hash was the only thing needed to make my url sharable, but when I paste it in the address bar the page is empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need some JS to check the hashes when the page is opened and load the corresponding page then. There should be some plugin to automate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your structure, this should make your friendly hashes:

```
var pathname = $(this).find('a')[0].href.split('/'),
    l = pathname.length;
pathname = pathname[l-1] || pathname[l-2];
window.location.hash = "#!" + pathname;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7E73/1/)

---

Now to make the URLs shareable, you will need to execute a hash check on DOM ready and load the corresponding content.

If all the pages are in the same directory, you can do it directly:

```
 $(function() {
     var hash = window.location.hash;
     //checks if hash exists and is hash bang
     if (hash && hash.substring(0, 2) === '#!') {
         hash = hash.substring(2); //removes leading #!
         $('#content').load('path/to/' + hash);
     }
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7E73/3/show/#!test5)

If the pages aren't all in the same directory, you'll need to map the hashes to the addresses.

```
$(function() {
    var hashmap = {
        'test5': 'http://foobar.baz/fooz/test5',
        'anotherTest': 'http://foobar.baz/barz/anotherTest',
    };
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    //checks if hash exists and is hash bang
    if (hash && hash.substring(0, 2) === '#!') {
        hash = hash.substring(2); //removes leading #!
        if (hashmap[hash]) { //checks if hash exist in the hash map
            $('#content').load(hashmap[hash]);
        }
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7E73/8/show/#!test5)

I'm using alerts in the demos above as the loading will fail. Of course you have to adapt/replace the `$('#content').load` by your preferred load method.

Comment: Woaw, I was only waiting for the first part of your answer... Thank you very much! I'm trying the shareable part but I'm not sure I'm adding it the right way. Here is what the console returns when I refresh a page `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #TagSelectah a[href=#!test4]`. I suspect a conflict with a plugin I'm using (filterable.pack.js) since filterable already adds a hash when I select an element in the "#TagSelectah" list. I'll dig around it...

Comment: I tried to remove the filterable plugin and it still isn't working, but I think it because the container is loaded only on click event. I think the solution is to make it open if a hash is detected on the address bar when the page is loading... What do you think about it? Could you help me writing this? Here is a jsfiddle so you know what I'm really dealing with. http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/19/

Comment: Make an empty container so it is always there. Not too sure what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: Not working. I'm loading the post content on a div that appears only if I click an item from a list. My problem is that if someone shares an url from the site, I need this div to be already there or to open on page load. I'll start a new thread cause I'm getting too far from the original question.

Comment: Hi @Fabrício, I've created a new thread about it. I'd appreciate your help if you have a minute.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292410/saving-and-loading-the-ajax-state-of-a-page