# saving and loading the ajax state of a page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on an ajax loading function on a Wordpress single page portfolio.

The principle is that when you click a thumbnail in the gallery, it opens a container (#DrawerContainer) and fetch the ajax content of this article into it. With a lot of help, I'm already able to open the drawer and load the post content when I click a thumbnail.

Here is a fiddle if you want to see it working (the ajax will not load but it works locally). http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/24/

**The part I'm working on now:** I need my site to be crawlable and the urls to be shareable. If I give `http://mywebsite.com/#!project5` to someone, I need project5 content to be opened when he loads the page.
I thought the hash-bang (#!) urls was the way to go to make this work. With the code below (commented on the jsfiddle), I can update the url and add the hash of the clicked thumbnail.

```
var pathname = $(this).find('a')[0].href.split('/'),
            l = pathname.length;
        pathname = pathname[l-1] || pathname[l-2];
        window.location.hash = "#!" + pathname;
```

But when I load a page, the ajax state isn't remembered. I assumed it was because my ajax container was only loaded on click event, but there is no change when I add a persistant container in the php.

Is there a way to load the page with a post content already displayed, or to open the #DrawerContainer when the page is loading a hash-bang url?

Please keep in mind that I'm just learning jquery and ajax. So I'd really appreciate if you explain or comment a little bit what you do, I'll for sure learn at the same time... :)

Comment: Ene's approach looks good, I've commented on it. If you need further help, updating the fiddle to reflect the html structure better will greatly help - e.g. there are no links inside of the list items, it'd be nice to see how their href looks like (e.g. `/foo/` or `/foo` or `http://example.com/foo/bar`)

Comment: I just updated the fiddle (see the first thumbnail) so you have my exact structure. The `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` is returning this `http://example.com/foo/` and with the hash it looks like this `http://example.com/#!foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on onload you should check the window.location.hash and trigger a click on the particular link/div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if ( hash.length > 0 ) {
        hash = hash.replace('#' , '' , hash );
        $('a[rel="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks good, however, replacing/removing the `#!` instead of `#` and using `[href$=` instead of `[rel=` will probably yield better results.

Comment: I tried both of your codes with no positive effect. But if I understand it well, I think I'll have to dig in this direction.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, this function is supposed to check which hash is in the address bar and triggers a click on the corresponding thumbnail when the page is loading? Is that right?

Comment: Here's an updated version of Ene's answer using the [Attribute Ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) matching the `href` attribute - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/26/) (at the bottom of the script). Hopefully it should be of some use.

Comment: Thank you Fabrício, we are super close!! When I reload a page the drawer open and close in a very short amount of time (I dont even see the content). Same result in Ie,  and in firefox my images are gone. The only difference with the code you have is that the click is detected on `'#portfolio-list>div:not(#DrawerContainer)'` and not on `div`. I updated the jsfiddle anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/28/
Please tell me if you see something else that could prevent the opening... I'll try to echo or alert more info on my side.

Comment: I've found the part responsible of closing the drawer when the page is reloading. I removed this: `if(LastInRow.next().attr('id') == 'DrawerContainer' && LastInRow.next().data('citem') == this) { LastInRow.next().slideToggle() setTimeout(function(){ // then remove... $('#DrawerContainer').remove(); }, 500); }` now your code is working great, thank you guys! Just one last thing, I can't close the drawer anymore if I click on `#current`. Could you help me fixing it? Here is my updated code http://jsfiddle.net/RF6df/30/

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following on sites where I want to trigger via hash changes.

First I bind a hashchange event to get the hash value

```
 $(window).bind('hashchange', function(o){

            url = window.location.hash.substring(1);

            o.preventDefault();



        if (!url) {
            return;
        }

 }
```

Then I trigger the hashchange when I want - in your case when the page loads i.e. on document ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

You can then use the hash value in your function that loads the correct content

Comment: The question was about opening the page, not clicking on a link.

Comment: That is why I trigger the hashchange when the page loads. when the document is ready then it triggers the hashchange function which gets the current hash value which can then be used to load in the correct content - this means the same function can be used for both clicking the link and loading the page

Comment: Thanks @KevPrice but your first code is making my browser jump to another page instead of loading the content in the home.